# What should I do If I was told by email that I would receive the offer letter within 2-3 working days but it has been 5 days since then?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, international, job-satisfaction, job-security

I was offered a job in a big company in the UAE but I am in Pakistan. I was hired and was told by the manager that my documents have been forwarded to HR and I will receive the OFFER LETTER within 2-3 days, plus I should proceed with the paperwork but it's been 5 days since the mail and I haven't received any job offer letter from them via email?

What should I do? Should I mail them to confirm the status etc? What should I do?

Comment: Check your spam folder.

Comment: So is it 2-3 days or 3-4 days? Your title and body suggest different things

Comment: If they said "up to 4 days" maybe they meant 4 business days (i.e. weekends and holidays don't count).

Comment: Leave it a week, then ask them if they sent any documents yet, and if they have a tracking number.

Comment: Make sure, it's not a scam: http://dubaiofw.com/how-to-spot-job-scammers-fake-jobs/

Answer (score 6):

You should wait at most 7 days before inquiring about the offer letter. You should contact them via email first confirming that you have the job.

Then if you still get no response call them up, don't let them avoid you. As they do have to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do? Should I mail them to confirm the status etc? What should I do?

Yes definitely email them and reach out to them. I would make an all out effort to contact them to confirm if they are still interested.

On your side, do nothing to prepare for a new job. Do NOT put in your notice or prepare anything yet and DO continue applying to other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the perspective of someone who has worked on offer letters it is likely that there is a delay in getting it prepared. There could be several reason for this. Maybe the person in charge of writing the letter is sick or out on leave. So it may take a little longer to get it done with a backup or they may be waiting on that person to return. It could be that there is some red tape that HR is preventing them from getting it out until some requirement is met. Or they may have forgot as they are already reviewing other perspective employees for other positions and have just not had the time to finish the offer letter.

In any case If you were told 2 to 3 days I would email them by 5 to 7 business days (not including weekends or holidays) and or call them. Just a friendly "Hi there. I am just checking in on the offer letter. Wanted to make sure you were not missing anything from me as it has been nearly a week since our last correspondence." Not in those exact words but you get the general idea.